# Using (or not using) parentheses when initializing an array

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

In the c++ code that I am reading through there are some arrays initialised like

```
int *foo = new int[length];
```

and some like

```
int *foo = new int[length]();
```

My quick experimentation could not detect any difference between these two, yet they are used right next to one another.

Is there a difference, if so what?

Edit; since there is an assertion that the first one should give indeterminate output here is a test showing a suspicious number of 0s;

```
[s1208067@hobgoblin testCode]$ cat arrayTest.cc
//Test how array initilization works
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int length = 30;
//Without parenthsis
int * bar = new int[length];
for(int i=0; i<length; i++) cout << bar[0] << " ";

cout << endl;
//With parenthsis 
int * foo = new int[length]();
for(int i=0; i<length; i++) cout << foo[0] << " ";


cout << endl;
return 0;
}
[s1208067@hobgoblin testCode]$ g++ arrayTest.cc
[s1208067@hobgoblin testCode]$ ./a.out
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
[s1208067@hobgoblin testCode]$
```

Edit 2; apparently this test was flawed, dont trust it - look at the answers for details

Comment: No there is no difference, its just calling the constructor which takes no parameters

Comment: @nilo, `int` does not have a default constructor (for the edit, or any constructor), and there is a difference.

Comment: `int` does have a default constructor - try `cout << int() << endl`.

Comment: @celticminstrel, You're printing a value-initialized `int`. Same syntax doesn't imply that it has a default constructor. (For reference, *The expression T(), where T is a simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier for a non-array complete object
type or the (possibly cv-qualified) void type, creates a prvalue of the specified type, whose value is that
produced by value-initializing (8.5) an object of type T; no initialization is done for the void() case.*)

Comment: See [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new) This is case A, and is the same in C++11.

Comment: I've never actually seen the parentheses with array initialization.

Comment: @chris That is not exactly true. Bjarne himself said that "Built-in types are considered to have constructors (whatever words the standard use to describe their behavior).". They might not have a construct like a class as member function but I guess thats a flaw in the design of c++, making it confusing. Some say direct initialization some say constructor even though it might be incorrect.

Comment: @nilo, Yes, you could think of them being special non-class types with constructors. Unfortunately, it doesn't always work out so consistently. You would expect that `int x;` uses the "default constructor" and that `int x = int();` also uses the default constructor because that's what happens when you replace `int` with a suitable user-defined type. However, they actually do different things. I guess the better analogy would be the behaviour of `struct S {int x;};` when doing `S s;` and `S s  = S();`, though it's about as intuitive as the plain `int` case.

Comment: @chris I agree, I've done some research and I think that calling direct initialization for constructor (for built-in types) is wrong since it doesn't behave like class constructors which people associate the word constructor to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the parentheses guarantees that all elements of the array are initialized to 0. I just tried using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int,char*[]){
    int* foo = new int[8];
    cout << foo << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        foo[i] = i;
    delete[] foo;
    foo = new int[8];
    cout << foo << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        cout << foo[i] << '\t';
    cout << endl;
    delete[] foo;
    foo = new int[8]();
    cout << foo << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        cout << foo[i] << '\t';
    cout << endl;
    delete[] foo;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run this, it looks like `foo` is allocated in the same memory location each time (though you probably can't rely on this). The full output of the above program for me is:

```
0x101300900
0x101300900
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   
0x101300900
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

So, you can see that the second allocation of `foo` doesn't touch the memory allocated, leaving it in the same state that it was left in from the first allocation.

Answer (score 13):

This line [*default*-initializes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) `length` `int`s, which is to say you will get a bunch of `int`s with indeterminate value:

```
int *foo = new int[length];
```

This line [*value*-initializes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) them instead, so you get all zeros:

```
int *foo = new int[length]();
```

Comment: In quick experimentation both seem to have only 0s in. Is this just chance for the first version?

Comment: @Jekowl, Yes, printing them in the first case is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Jekowl Are you in debug build?

Comment: @Chris I'm compiling with $ g++ fileName.cc in the terminal (then running the resulting file) I don't think that's debug mode?

Comment: I get the same results with clang - in the first case, it outputs all 0's.

Comment: Indeterminate doesn't mean "not 0". It means "can be anything." Having them happen to be 0 is acceptable, but not something you should rely on.

Comment: @Barry yes, but it would seem surprising to get 10 zeros in a row that way. Possible however, which is why I was asking.

Comment: Acceptable under the standard, certainly, but it looks like it's being zero-initialized both ways...

Comment: This answer seems correct in all respects. The other one had the advantage of explaining the thing that looks surprising.

Comment: @Jekowl You accept the answer that you feel helped you the most - you don't have to explain it. I won't take it personally :)